# Chrome drops session cookie

Tags: google-chrome, session, firefox, cookies, paypal

I have a perplexing problem. I am using php sessions to track info across a shopping site and the session is correctly carried in Chrome all through the process. I can even leave the site and go net surfing and come back and see the sessionid is still there, as I should. I am offering PayPal as an option for purchases but when a user completes the purchase on PayPal, the redirect is not getting the session info. I appears the session is either deleted or blocked. It remains on the server because I can go back and see it is still there  with all the stored values, it just isn't getting access. This is happening in Firefox as well, but everyhting is working fine in IE and Safari. I have heard this is a secuirty issue with Chrome, but does anyone know what causes it and is there a work around?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHPSESSID cookie in Developer Tools to see if it's still there or has changed?

Comment: Yes, I checked and the PHPSESSID is there and it is persistant. The only time it seems to be unavailable is on return from PayPal. I checked and the sessionid is the same and is there, but when redirected back to the site from PayPal it doesn't get the session and so directs the user to the first page and sets a new session id. I had a similar issue with another site and I made the URLs relative and that fixed the issue, but not possible when PayPal is used.